# Reaching "self" in closure defined in class

Tags: ios, macos, swift, cocoa, closures

So I have the following structure and was curious if this was possible.

```
class Chip8
{

    let foo = 10;

    let mapping = [

        // CLS (clear the display)
        0x00E0: { (argument: Int) -> Void in
             // How can I reach self.foo here (self.foo obviously does not work, which is the premise of the question)
         },

    ]
}
```

Is something like this possible?

edit:

Seems that if I move the initialization of the mapping to the constructor I can access "self"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try

```
class Chip8
{

    let foo = 10;

    lazy var mapping:[Int: (Int)->Void] = {
        return [

            // CLS (clear the display)
            0x00E0: { (argument: Int) -> Void in
                // How can I reach self.foo here (self.foo obviously does not work, which is the premise of the question)
                self.foo
            },

        ]
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've moved the initialization of the mapping to the init constructor, and now I can access "self" from the closures in the mapping.

Comment: BTW, if you have a closure property that references `self`, you might want to use `[weak self] in` or `[unowned self] in` syntax in order to avoid strong reference cycle. See the "Strong Reference Cycles for Closures" section under [Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48) chapter of _The Swift Programming Language._